# Encrypt\decrypt a part of big file using salsa20

Tags: c#, file, encryption, ram

I have homework from my university teacher. I have to write code which will encrypt\decrypt small part of big file (about 10GB). I use algorithm Salsa20. 
The main thing is not to load RAM. As he said, I should read, for example, 100 lines then encrypt\decrypt it, write to file and back.

I create List

```
List<string> dict = new List<string>();
```

Read lines (because reading all bytes is loading lots of RAM)

```
using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
  while (dict.Count < 100)
  {
    dict.Add(sReader.ReadLine());
  }
}
```

Try to create one line from

```
string words = string.Join("", dict.ToArray());
```

Encrypt this line

```
string encrypted;
using (var salsa = new Salsa20.Salsa20())
using (var mstream_out = new MemoryStream())
{
  salsa.Key = key;
  salsa.IV = iv;
  using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(mstream_out, 
  salsa.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
  {
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words);
    cstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  }
  encrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mstream_out.ToArray());
}
```

Then I need to write 100 lines of encrypted string, but I don't know how to do it! Is there any solution?

Comment: So your question is 'How do I write strings to a file'??

Comment: yes, but if you found mistakes, please, tell me

Comment: i tried to write encrypted strings, but when i was trying to decrypt it, nothing

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's what you could do.

Accept a filename, a starting line number and an ending line number.

Read the lines, simply writing them them to another file if they are lower than the starting line number or larger than the ending line number.

Once you read a line that is in the range, you can encrypt it with the key and an IV. You will possibly need to encode it to a byte array e.g. using UTF-8 first, as modern ciphers such as Salsa operate on bytes, not text.

You can use the line number possibly as nonce/IV for your stream cipher, if you don't expect the number of lines to change. Otherwise you can prefix the ciphertext with a large, fixed size, random nonce.

The ciphertext - possibly including the nonce - can be encoded as base64 without line endings. Then you write the base 64 line to the other file.

Keep encrypting the lines until you found the end index. It is up to you if your ending line is inclusive or exclusive.

Now read the remaining lines, and write them to the other file.

Don't forget to finalize the encryption and close the file. You may possibly want to destroy the source input file.

---

Encrypting bytes may be easier as you could write to the original file. However, writing encrypted strings will likely always expand the ciphertext compared with the plaintext. So you need to copy the file, as it needs to grow from the middle out.

---

I haven't got a clue why you would keep a list or dictionary in memory. If that's part of the requirements then I don't see it in the rest of the question. If you read in all the lines of a file that way then clearly you're using up memory.

Of course, if your 4 GiB file is just a single line then you're still using way too much memory. In that case you need to stream *everything*, parsing text from files, putting it in a character buffer, character-decoding it, encrypting it, encoding it again to base 64 and writing it to file. Certainly doable, but tricky if you've never done such things.

Comment: if I read bytes, I'm loading much RAM. It's not possible for my task(

Comment: That statement doesn't make any sense, my dear padawan. A byte has a rather specific size of, well 8 bits or one byte. There are of course ways of reading files partially. Most high level languages have streaming implementations and some also have an interface to memory mapping of the file, offered by the OS. Anyway most of my answer was about operating on lines, as you indicated that this was probably what was required.